# How to set QR version with Endroid\QR Code

Tags: php, symfony, qr-code

I am generating QR code with Endroid\QRCode library. Everything works fine, but library output QR version 10, which is not good for me. How can set it to output QR version 15?

https://github.com/endroid/qr-code-bundle

```php
$content = "Demo QR code";
$qrCode = new QrCode($content);
$qrCode->setSize(600);
$qrCode->setErrorCorrectionLevel(new ErrorCorrectionLevel(ErrorCorrectionLevel::MEDIUM));
$qrCode->setEncoding('ISO-8859-2');

$dir = $this->getParameter('qr_directory');
$filename = 'order-'.$order->getId().'.png';
$qrCode->writeFile($dir.$filename);
```

I expect the output version will be 15, but actual output is 10.

Comment: Did you finally find how to set the version ?

Comment: I edited Bacon library which is underlying. There is function which choose best version based on data.